# Migrate after removing ForeignKey to third-party model

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I'm in the process of removing some dead code in a project and I have the opportunity to remove a dependency on a third-party app that we've been using since we started the project.  One of our models has a ForeignKey to a model in the third-party app and I'm running into trouble when trying to apply migrations on a fresh instance of the project.

An example model:

```
from django.db import models
from thirdparty.models import ThirdPartyModel

class MyModel(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(ThirdPartyModel)
```

Removing `MyModel.fk` is detected by South and the migration is created successfully.  Applying the migration and rolling it back works too.  I can now remove `thirdparty` from `INSTALLED_APPS` and commit the changes (the new migration and `settings.py`).

The trouble starts when I clone the repository on another machine.  `./manage.py syncdb` runs as expected and creates all the tables not managed by South but `./manage.py migrate myapp` fails when creating the table for (an early version of) `MyModel` because the foreign key to `thirdparty_thirdpartymodel` cannot be created (as expected because `thirdparty` is no longer in `INSTALLED_APPS` so none of the tables are created).

Are there standard ways to handle removing external dependencies?  Is this an appropriate time to reset my migrations?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it is still valid and even independent of South and would also be an issue with Django Migrations.

You should take care that the migration files are separated in a way that you can fake the migrations that depend on the non-existing app (removed from `INSTALLED_APPS`). That way, you would go about creating new installations by faking those migrations, and actually running those migrations on existing installations.

Of course, if you have the possibility to start over (like a complete relaunch), you could wipe your database, remove all existing migration files and simply create completely new migrations. All other developers would have to drop their databases, as well.

In case you have existing production data and still want to start from scratch, there are different possibilities on how to transfer the data.
Which way is best depends on how much data there is, how much the structure has changed etc:

- plain SQL (change the DB by hand, after running the new migrations, by transferring the data from old tables into new and dropping the tables, and foreign keys etc.)
- fixtures (dump the data via Django in the old system and change the JSON to fit the new structure)
- two parallel installations of the old and new system and transfer via Django/Python scripts (slower than plain SQL but you can make use of the Django Model logic, apply validation checks, transformations etc. in a more comfortable way).

Of course, don't do this in production but somewhere else and simply apply the result.